# CAn't rename ACCESS database or move it

Tags: ms-access, office365

Creating a new ACCESS application. When I first open ACCESS and create new database it works fine, but is saved on the PC as Database71.  If I save it as with a new name to the desk top, or try to rename it it won't open with the following message:  WARNING: It is impossible to determine that this content came from a reliable source.  I have swept the web and tried several of the solutions,  involving the ACCESS Options and the trust center. but none of them work. 
Using OFFICE 365 and Windows 10.

jpl458

Comment: I've heard that achange to the registry is required to make access trusted.  Is this true?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if you get an executable file from the Internet - and I assume that's where your first database is created using Office 365 - then when you copy to your PC it will mark it as unsafe.

If I remember right, you can right-click on the PC database, select properties and then there used to be a button that said "UnBlock" in the bottom right hand corner - or possibly under Advanced.

If that doesn't work, there's a [Microsoft Powershell script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/unblock-file?view=powershell-6) that will do the same thing.

Comment: Didn't get it from internet. All in house home brew.  Thanks for your response though.

Answer (score -1):

After you move or rename the file, when you next try to open it, go to the folder where the file is and right click the file and select Open With.  In my case there were two ACCESS 2016s.  The lower one opened just fine.  I have Office 365 so I can't say why there are two entries for 2016.  This just works.

Comment: Not really helpful.